# output grouped results with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo

I'm currently having a hard time finding a way to display the results of a PDO query the way I would like.

I'm just learning PHP/PDO and MySQL through a little task I've set myself.My select query is below.

```
try{
$sth=$dbh->prepare("SELECT backup.bakLoc, client.cliName, project.prjName, assistant.astName, session.sessDate, session.stdID, backup.bakID, backup.bakName, backup.bakDate, backup.bakKeep, backup.recLoc, backup.bakDeleted
                    FROM session
                    INNER JOIN studio ON session.stdID=studio.stdID
                    INNER JOIN engineer ON session.engID=engineer.engID
                    INNER JOIN assistant ON session.astID=assistant.astID
                    INNER JOIN client ON session.cliID=client.cliID
                    INNER JOIN project ON session.prjID=project.prjID
                    INNER JOIN composer ON session.cmpID=composer.cmpID
                    INNER JOIN fixer ON session.fixID=fixer.fixID
                    LEFT JOIN backup ON session.bakID=backup.bakID
                    WHERE session.stdID = :stdID AND (ISNULL(backup.bakDeleted) OR backup.bakDeleted =0)
                    ORDER BY session.stdID,backup.bakLoc,sessDate; ");

 $sth->bindParam(':stdID', $_GET['studio'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

 $sth->execute();



}
catch(PDOException $e) {
   print $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem I'm having relates to the way you output the result of this query.

id like to group the output by the backup.bakLoc column. That column can have one of four results either NULL, 1,2 or 3. I would like to output this to html with a seperate header for each set of results rather than to set up 4 querys with varying clauses. To accomplish it in the past i just ended up dumping each column into its own array and then iterating the output with a couple of if statements to watch for the column values changing or just running a query under each heading with the WHERE clause changing. There must be a more direct way of doing it.

So on the page like this

```
<h1>Not Backed Up</h1>
    //all results of when $row['bakLoc'] is NULL or 0
<?=$row['bakName']; ?><br />

<h1>backup location 1</h1>
   //all results of when $row['bakLoc'] is 1
<?=$row['bakName']; ?><br />
```

etc etc

I've been playing with PDO::FETCH_GROUP but I can't get it to work as i'd like. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction for splitting up results like this without the need for multiple queries. (that is of course unless multiple queries is the best way to go.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for counts of each occurrence of backup.bakLoc, this would give you a single record with counts for each of the 4 backLoc values:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN backup.bakLoc IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) backLoc_null,
        SUM(CASE WHEN backup.bakLoc = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) backLoc_1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN backup.bakLoc = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) backLoc_2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN backup.bakLoc = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) backLoc_3

<the rest of your query>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm looking for a way to output all of the results under a group header though. The count of each row may be useful to know how many iterations through the results before the value of bakLoc changes.

I've actually kind of sorted a way to answer myself by wrapping the query and the echo statement into a function and passing it the bakLoc value as a variable. I then call this function 4 times for each value of bakLoc within my html to correctly display the data as rows under their corresponding <h> tag. Just looking for a 'smarter' way. Thank you again.